# Skype doesn't always sign me in automatically

Tags: windows-7, skype

I have Skype set up to sign me in automatically on startup, but it doesn't always do so.  Sometimes, it opens and just sits at the login screen until I find out about it a few hours later when my co-workers start asking me why I'm not online.

What could be causing this random behavior?  I am using Windows 7 32-bit.

**Edit:**  I will also add that I am often greeted with the message `Your session has timed out.  Please try again.` when attempting to sign in after a failed auto-sign-in.  My retry attempt is always successful.

**Edit 2:**  It appears I've stumbled into another one of those issues that have tons of other people asking questions, but not a single person giving any answers.

http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/expired-session/td-p/1346292
http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/Your-session-has-timed-out-Please-try-again/td-p/1530251
http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20071126163051AAoDec0

Does SE have what it takes?

**Update:** I believe I have a theory and it involves shutting down Skype improperly (ie, terminating the process either through task manager or logging off Windows and telling Windows to close the program).  I just terminated the process and restarted it and was asked to sign in.  My theory is that, when the Skype process is terminated, the app closes, but the session still somehow remains open.  After so long, it expires.  The next day when Skype opens, it attempts to use the same session since it wasn't shut down properly.  This results in the "session expired" message.  The reason why it works the second time is because now it knows to start up a new session.  Again, it's only a theory, but I am going to test it by terminating Skype before I leave and then expecting the issue to occur tomorrow morning.

Comment: Are you logging in from multiple locations by chance?

Comment: Nope.  I only use Skype at work.  I login at home, but maybe only a couple times a month.  I haven't used Skype at home any time recently.

Comment: Try to reset Skype Settings
http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows/Skype-auto-logs-off/m-p/938210/highlight/true#M69026